# Is there an in-universe explanation as to why the Borg look and behave differently in The Next Generation than in First Contact/Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, borg

Is there an in-universe explanation, not just about the way they look, but for the fact the Borg behave differently in The Next Generation, compared to First Contact and Voyager?

Guinan's comments about the Borg in The Next Generation imply that they are completely different to the Borg in *Voyager* and *First Contact*.

Comment: Comments moved [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34872/discussion-on-question-by-darren-is-there-an-in-universe-explanation-as-to-why-t)